# Connect to Aurora Serverless using EC2 as Proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, serverless, amazon-aurora

Not a duplicate of [AWS Aurora MySQL serverless: how to connect from MySQL Workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51716530/aws-aurora-mysql-serverless-how-to-connect-from-mysql-workbench).

Aurora Serverless doesn't support public connections yet.

I used Cloud9 to create an EC2 instance on the same VPN as the database. I then connected to the database from the Cloud9 terminal.

My (GraphQL Prisma) service that I'm attempting to host (on Zeit Now) only takes a HOST and a PASSWORD for configuration.

How can I make the EC2 instance act as a proxy that I can treat exactly as a database endpoint. Can tunneling fully do that and I'm just bad at it?

Comment: Seems like you want to be able to hit the DB directly from a public IP address.  A NAT gateway might be more appropriate for tunneling to a private endpoint.  Serverless Aurora does create network interfaces that NAT should be able to point to.

Comment: @BenBalentine you could provide us an example? Currently, I want to create a tunnel to my aurora serverless cluster.

Answer (score 1):

I think this [blog](https://medium.com/@griggheo/accessing-a-private-rds-instance-via-an-ssh-tunnel-4be098b128ef) may help you. The idea, is make a forwarding port from ec2-dns:3306 to aurora-serverless-cluster-dns:3306

Comment: Thank you! I may take a little while to test and select the best answer as I moved forward with a traditional RDS instance, but I will come back to and address this serverless route as a preferred solution.