# How can I connect to my serverless RDS instance from the public internet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

Using Aurora on RDS serverless

- VPC is connected to an ACL that allows traffic on 3306
- routing table connected to IGW that routes traffic to the public internet

Tried connecting to the endpoint listed in "Connectivity & security"

- Cannot ping my endpoint
- Cannot telnet to the endpoint
- Can resolve the endpoint
- Cannot connect from C#
- Cannot connect from `mysql -h ENDPOINT 3306` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: Serverless RDS Instances do not support public access.

During configuration you won't be able to see this toggle, and your instance, while running, will not be visible from the public internet:

[image: configuration of public access for RDS instance]

Answer (score 1):

Since as @fastmultiplication said, you can't access serverless RDS from the public internet, you will need to [connect using an SSH tunnel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52448301/connect-to-aurora-serverless-using-ec2-as-proxy). You can also set it up using [MySQL Workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51716530/aws-aurora-mysql-serverless-how-to-connect-from-mysql-workbench).

Comment: This is no longer the rule with serverless V2, however it is still an option that might help some.