# Unable to connect to server: timeout expired AWS aurora rds

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-aurora-serverless

I am trying to connect my AWS aurora database with pgAdmin 4 and it throws this error. I have tried all the previous solutions provided by the stack overflow answers like add inbound my IP and update pg_hab.conf. It still not working for me. Thank you in advance.

[Error facing with pgAdmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAxob.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I connect to my serverless RDS instance from the public internet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67655463/how-can-i-connect-to-my-serverless-rds-instance-from-the-public-internet)

Comment: This has been already done. @enharmonic

Answer (score 3):

Aurora serverless can be only accessed from within VPC. It has **no public Ip** address. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.html):

> You can't give an Aurora Serverless v1 DB cluster a public IP address. You can access an Aurora Serverless v1 DB cluster **only from within a VPC**.

This means you either have to connect to it from an EC2 instance running in the same VPC, or setup ssh tunneling or VPN connection between your local computer and the aurora. How to setup **ssh tunnel** is explained [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/best-practices-for-working-with-amazon-aurora-serverless/) and [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-connect-using-bastion-host-linux/).

Alternatively, use [DATA API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/data-api.html) to interact with your database from outside of a VPC.

Comment: Yes, my EC2 instance is running on the same VPC. In fact, my database is working fine with my backend server. All the I/O operation is working fine. The only issue which I am facing is that my database is not getting connect with my system pgAdmin 4 software.