# Is it possible to generate a diagram of AWS Aurora MySql serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-aurora

Is it possible to have a high-level with a diagram of tables, their columns and their jointures.

In MySql Workbench, it would look like this:

[image]

Is there any way to create this with lambdas  or any other way ?

Comment: Can’t you use MySQL Workbench to connect to Aurora MySQL and generate it that way?

Comment: Connections workbench to aurora serverless is unfortunately far from easy and tried all here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51716530/aws-aurora-mysql-serverless-how-to-connect-from-mysql-workbench with no success)

Answer (score 0):

I think your underlying problem is that you were unable to connect your workbench to the cluster. I would recommend getting that to work rather than trying to work around with a query that can provide you some sort of ascii art for the table structures.

Connecting to VPC only services is a pretty common use case, I've quoted some steps here [1] [2]. Do try them out and see if you can establish workbench connectivity to your cluster.

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/a/57230236/3069919
[2] [Connect to Neptune on AWS from local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52575630/connect-to-neptune-on-aws-from-local-machine/52622164#52622164)