# Connect Aurora Severless from tableau desktop and tableau server

Tags: ssh-tunnel, tableau-api, aws-aurora-serverless

It's a follow up question that I asked earlier here on Stack Overflow
[Not able connect Amazon Aurora Serverless from SQL client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57660868/not-able-connect-amazon-aurora-serverless-from-sql-client)

I found a cool hack that is working perfectly for my **development** purpose with some tweaks and I know I should not use this on my **production** environment.

So as we know Aurora Serverless works only inside VPC. So make sure you are attempting to connect to Aurora within the VPC and the security group assigned to the Aurora cluster has the appropriate rules to allow access. As I mention earlier that I already have an EC2 instance, Aurora Serverless and a VPC around both. So I can access it from my EC2 but not from my local pc/ local sql client. To fix that I did below two steps.

**1. To access from any client(Navicat in my case),**

a. First need to add **GENERAL** db configurations like aurora endpoint host, username, password etc.
b. Then, need to add **SSH** configuration, like EC2 machine username, hostip and .pem file path

[image]

[image]

**2. To access from project,**

First I create a **ssh tunnel** from my terminal like this way,

```
ssh ubuntu@my_ec2_ip_goes_here -i rnd-vrs.pem -L 5555:database-1.my_aurora_cluster_url_goes_here.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432
```

Then run my project with db configuration like this way **test.php**,

```
$conn = pg_connect("host=127.0.0.1 port=5555 dbname=postgres user=postgres password=password_goes_here");

// other code goes here to get data from your database
if (!$conn) {
    echo "An error occurred.\n";
    exit;
}

$result = pg_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM brands");
if (!$result) {
    echo "An error occurred.\n";
    exit;
}

while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "Brand Id: $row[0]  Brand Name: $row[1]";
    echo "<br />\n";
}
```

So **what is my question now?**

I need to connect my aurora serverless from tableau desktop and tableau server. For tableau desktop I used the same ssh tunneling and it works but how do I do it for tableau server?

Answer (score 1):

Tableau Server does not support centralized data sources. You need to connect Tableau Desktop to your data source, and publish it to Tableau Server when you want to expose the data through the UI.

https://community.tableau.com/thread/111282

Comment: so do you mean when I publish it from my Desktop version then only the extracted data will available on the server version, what if I need the latest(Live) dataset on my Tableau Server version?

Comment: Imagine I created a report 1year back, now I need to visualize it on Tableau Server with recent date's dataset how can I do that with Amazon Aurora Serverless because they don't provide to access it outside of the VPC, for local development, I can use ssh tunneling but what about the Table Server version?

Comment: Do you have any other way to access Aurora Serverless from Tableau server?

Comment: How do you usually connect MySQL DB with Tableau Server for live data? Should be able to work backwards from there..

Comment: For myself or postgres we use the aws rds host, username and password but for Aurora Serverless it's not possible because of vpc. So how can we do connect?