# Windows to Neptune connection succeeded- How to use it further?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-neptune

I have followed this :[Connect to Neptune on AWS from local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52575630)

Instead of changing this file C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts, I changed C:\Users\user_name.ssh\config file as below:

```
Host 10.100.128.00 
  Hostname 10.100.128.00
  Port 22
  User ec2-user
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my-ec2.pem
```

then I ran: `ssh -L 8182:<neptune endpoint>:8182 <bastion server ip>`

Now the **status** check worked but how can I use this connection to achieve other things(create vertices/edge) in Neptune? Can someone help with that?

Answer (score 2):

Amazon Neptune is a graph database, supporting the RDF and PropertyGraph data models. To add/delete/modify data you need to use one of the three supported query languages:

- W3C SPARQL
- Apache TinkerPop Gremlin
- openCypher

There is a lot of tutorial information and videos [here](https://aws.amazon.com/neptune/developer-resources/) I would also recommend setting up a graph-notebook and working through some of the example notebooks. You can setup a graph-notebook locally, and still connect to Neptune over an SSH tunnel.