# Connecting to AWS NeptuneDB Cluser from Local

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-neptune

I've created a new Neptune DB cluster from my console, for me to connect to the endpoint I made use of the instance endpoint given it's of the form `d-1.cluster-xxxxxx.eu-west-1.neptune.amazonaws.com`. I also created a new IAM user with ALLAdminstrative access and made use of the access key and secret key in establishing connection.

Whenever I try to hit the endpoint from my local I get a 500 `connect ETIMEDOUT 1x2.x1.x0.xxx:8182` error.

How do I connect to the NeptuneDB as appropriate? (I'm building my app in NodeJS)

P.S: I'm new to using AWS and its console.

I tried connecting to a new AWS NeptuneDB Cluser from my local but I'm getting a `connect ETIMEDOUT 1x2.x1.x0.xxx:8182` errror

Comment: Neptune does not expose a public DNS endpoint. You have to provide a way to access the VPC (there are many options). Please see the answers to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52575630/connect-to-neptune-on-aws-from-local-machine for a few such options.

Comment: Just following up. Were you able to get a connection configured using an ALB, SSH Tunnel or similar? If not, happy to help more.

Comment: @KelvinLawrence yes I got it to work using ALB, wasn't easy to setup at first but I'm now connected. Moving to querying the DB with gremlin and visualizing the data itself :)

Answer (score 0):

- A non AWS way to run `NeptuneDB` locally is [here](https://docs.localstack.cloud/user-guide/aws/neptune/).
  All they are doing here is packaging Gremlin server and using it as an endpoint for Gremlin queries. You can do this with Apache TinkerPop Gremlin server as well
- Another approach is to have a Notebook attached to the cluster so that you can test your gremlin/SparQL queries using the notebook/workbench as outlined [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/graph-notebooks.html)
- If you are looking to connect via http CURL, then you can use Neptune endpoint in CURL command as documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-rest.html)
- Another approach is to use gremlin console as detailed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-console.html)

Comment: This isn't the best approach for a production DB though :(

Comment: The original question was about connecting to Neptune from a local machine. The other post mentioned in the comments above addresses that specific ask. Neptune today does not expose a public DNS.