# I got the following error " Can't connect to MySQL server on <Aurora serverless endpoint> "

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

We tried to migrate from an Amazon Aurora database to Amazon Aurora serverless using the mysqldump command.
This is what We did

- First, get the SQL file with the database and its records using
  mysqldump -h  -u   -p  > db_schema_name.sql
- The first part didn't get us in any trouble, but the second part did.
  We used the following command to execute the SQL file in our Aurora serverless.
  mysql -h  -u   -p  < db_schema_name.sql
  yet we got this error
  Can't connect to MySQL server on .
  Has anyone ever encountered this error? If you have. How did you solve it?

Comment: there seems to be some limitations see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51716530/aws-aurora-mysql-serverless-how-to-connect-from-mysql-workbench

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to connect from?